# QNetwork TLS portable

Tags: qt, ssl

I want to build TLS application using QT for Android and iOS devices. How portable is the underlying implementation because it seems there are dependancies on the OS? Or is it better to build and test with own TLS like mBed TLS for both devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qt support multiple banckends to provide TLS.

On Android the default is to use OpenSSL, but the binaries are not provided with Qt due to some legal restrictions. For more details see: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/opensslsupport.html

On iOS the default, since Qt 5.5, is to use Apple SecureTransport framework. But you can change the behavior to use OpenSSL. See http://wiki.qt.io/Support_for_iOS_and_tvOS#https_support

In both cases Qt provides complete abstraction from the underlying backend. Meaning that you can change the backend at any time without changing your code.

I would recommend to go with the default configuration, unless you encounter issues that requires to use another backend.